# How do I add a number to a list of lists?

Tags: python, list, sum, element, addition

Let's say I have the list

```
[[1,2,3], [4,5,6]]
```

I want to add 5 to each element.

Then the new list would be [[6, 7, 8], [9, 10, 11]] as the answer.

```
def add(num, list):
```

Comment: Are you going to try to write some code at some point, or do you [expect people to write it for you](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23526265/how-do-i-combine-indexes-of-two-lists)? Oh wait...

Answer (score 5):

Just do a nested list comprehension (and don't use `list` as a name, it overrides the builtin):

```
def add(num, lst):
    return [[item+num for item in sub] for sub in lst]
```

Demo:

```
>>> test = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]]
>>> add(5, test)
[[6, 7, 8], [9, 10, 11]]
```

Comment: @AlexThomton Your solution looks simple, and when comparing to my "too smart" solution using partials, yours is also more then twice faster.

Comment: @user2581724 if this solved your problem, please consider accepting this answer, SO's standard way of saying "thank you"

Answer (score 2):

## Little excercise with partial and operator add

### There is `add` operator in `operator` module

```
>>> from operator import add
>>> add(7, 5)
12
```

### `functool` allows building new functions by `partial`

```
>>> from functools import partial
>>> add5 = partial(add, 5)
>>> add5(7)
12
```

### use `map` to apply `add5` on simple sublst

```
>>> sublst = [1,2,3]
>>> map(add5, sublst)
[6, 7, 8]
```

### Playing with nested list as requested

```
>>> lst = [[1,2,3], [4,5,6]]
>>> [map(add5, sublst) for sublst in lst]
[[6, 7, 8], [9, 10, 11]]
```

### Measuring execution time

Using already prepared function `add5`

```
>>> %timeit [map(add5, sublst) for sublst in lst]
1000000 loops, best of 3: 1.23 µs per loop
```

Using one of proposed answers:

```
>>> [[item+5 for item in sub] for sub in lst]
[[6, 7, 8], [9, 10, 11]]

>>> %timeit [[item+5 for item in sub] for sub in lst]
1000000 loops, best of 3: 658 ns per loop
```

With `add5` being created just at the moment we need it:

```
>>> [map(partial(add, 5), sublst) for sublst in lst]
[[6, 7, 8], [9, 10, 11]]
>>> %timeit [map(partial(add, 5), sublst) for sublst in lst]
1000000 loops, best of 3: 1.5 µs per loop
```

Making the `num` to be added variable:

```
>>> num = 5
>>> [map(partial(add, num), sublst) for sublst in lst]
[[6, 7, 8], [9, 10, 11]]
```

### Building the function required in the question

```
>>> def add2lst(num, lst):
...     return [map(partial(add, num), sublst) for sublst in lst]
...
```

and testing, it works

```
>>> add2lst(5, lst)
[[6, 7, 8], [9, 10, 11]]
```

## Conclusions - being too smart might slow things down

```
>>> timeit.timeit("[[item+5 for item in sub] for sub in lst]", setup="from functools import partial;from operator import add;lst=[[1,2,3],[4,5,6]]", number=rep)
6.1195290088653564
>>> timeit.timeit("[map(partial(add, 5), sublst) for sublst in lst]", setup="from functools import partial;from operator import add;lst=[[1,2,3],[4,5,6]]", number=rep)
14.058987140655518
```

Smart concept using operator and partial added complexity for execution, which results in this solution being more then twice as slow as the simple one.

So: **"keep it simple"**

Comment: +1 nice series of documented experiments, and I agree with the conclusion (I'd have favored either way unless there was a pressing need for speed, big fan of *"Simple is better than complex."* - Zen of Python)

Answer (score 1):

If you are willing to use `Numpy`:

```
import numpy as np

np.array([[1,2,3], [4,5,6]]) + 5
```

will add `5` element-wise returning:

```
array([[ 6,  7,  8],
       [ 9, 10, 11]])
```

Answer (score 0):

`map()` and a list comprehension does the job:

```
def add(num, lst):
    return [map(lambda x: x + num, l) for l in lst]
```