# How do I combine indexes of two lists?

Tags: python, list, matrix, indexing, sum

Let's say I have the lists [[1,2],[3,4]] and [[5,6],[7,8]]

I expect                   [[6, 8], [10, 12]] as the result.

I'm trying to sum up numbers according to their indexes.

```
def sum_matrix(num1, num2):
```

Comment: So where's the rest of the function?

Comment: You need to try harder.

Answer (score 2):

Another easy job for ndarrays:

```
>>> from numpy import array
>>> list1, list2 = [[1,2],[3,4]], [[5,6],[7,8]]
>>> (array(list1) + array(list2)).tolist()
[[6, 8], [10, 12]]
```

Answer (score 0):

onliner trivial recursive lambda:

```
sum_mtx = lambda (x, y): x+y if not isinstance(x, list) else map(sum_mtx, zip(x,y))
sum_mtx(([[1, 2], [3, 4]] ,[[5, 6], [7, 8]]))
# [[6, 8], [10, 12]]
```